# Fatal PDO Error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array in

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm getting an fatal error trying to run this, and I can't figure out why. The error is:

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array in C:\xxx.php on line 22

Line 22 is the line

```
if($resultaat['poop'] == 0){
```

Here is the full code

```
if ($db <> NULL) {


        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(leerlingen.bestemming) AS someVar FROM leerlingen, bestemmingen 
        WHERE leerlingen.bestemming = (SELECT bestemming FROM bestemmingen WHERE bestemmingsnummer =  $_GET[bestemmingsnummer]) ";
        $resultaat = $db->query($sql);


        if($resultaat['someVar'] == 0){

            echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
            echo 'alert("true.")'; 
            echo '</script>';
//              $sql = "DELETE FROM bestemmingen WHERE bestemmingsnummer =      $_GET[bestemmingsnummer]";
//              $resultaat = $db->exec($sql);
        }
        else{
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
            echo 'alert("false")'; 
            echo '</script>';  
        }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch the results first:

```
[...]
$db->query($sql);
$resultaat = $db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   

if($resultaat['someVar'] == 0){
[...]
```